# IE and Chrome Specific issue - Firefox works fine displaying navigation

Tags: html, css

When I resize my browser windows I am getting some unexpected behavior from IE and Chrome. The navigation menu does not stay locked in place.

I know the problem has something to do with the long text that is right justified with the logo. In this case, the "Comic Subscription..." text. When the "C" of this text comes to the edge of the last navigation menu item, that is when the navigation menu drops.

IE screenshot:
[Internet Explorer http://www.jaylefler.com/ie.png](http://www.jaylefler.com/ie.png)

Chrome screenshot:
[Chrome http://www.jaylefler.com/chrome.png](http://www.jaylefler.com/chrome.png)

Firefox screenshot:
[Firefox http://www.jaylefler.com/firefox.png](http://www.jaylefler.com/firefox.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

 <head>
 <title>Demolition Comics Subscription Management System</title>

 <style>

body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-color:#FAF8CC;
}

 nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color:rgb(255,200,0); 
    border-bottom:1px solid #000; 
    font-weight: bold;
}

nav ul{
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
    min-width: 755px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

nav ul li{
    float: left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    background-color:rgb(255,200,0);
    border-right:1px solid #000;
}

nav ul li a{
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    width:150px;
    height: 25px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    display:block;
    color:#000;
}

nav ul li ul{
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
    min-width: 150px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    margin-left: -1px;  
}

 nav ul li:hover ul{
    visibility: visible;
}

nav ul li ul li {
    float: none;
    width:200px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
}

nav ul li ul li a {
    text-align:center;
    width:200px;
}

nav a:hover {
    background-color:#000;
    color:rgb(255,200,0);
}

#logo {
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 800px;
    color: rgb(255,200,0);
    height: 100px;
    margin:0px;
}

#logo img {
    padding: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.left_part, .right_part {
    height: 100px;
}

.left_part {
    float: left;
}

.right_part {
    float:right;
    width:500px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: right;
}

.right_part a {
    line-height: 10x;
    color: rgb(255,200,0);
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:right;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding: 25px;
}

#contents, #footer {
    background:#fff;
    width:1024px;
    padding:20px;
    padding-top:5px;
}

#contents {
    margin:15px auto 0;
    border: 5px solid black;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
    /*box-shadow: 6px 6px 4px 4px #000;*/
    box-shadow: 10px 15px 5px #888888;
    min-height: 550px;
    background-color:#F0F7FF;
}

#footer {
    background-color: rgb(255,200,0);
    border-radius: 0 0 15px 15px;
    /*box-shadow: 6px 6px 4px 4px #000;*/
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
    border: 5px solid black;
    border-top:1px dashed #000;
    color:#000;
    margin:0 auto 40px;
}

.bigHead {
    font-size: 2em;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 22px;
}

.littleNavi {
    font-size: 1em;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="logo">

    <div class="left_part">
        <img src="demo.gif">
    </div>

   <div class="right_part"> 
        <div class="bigHead">Comic Subscription Management</div>
        <div class="littleNavi"><a href="index.php">CONTACT US</a> - <a href="#">FAQ</a> - <a href="index.php">ABOUT</a></div>
    </div>

</div>

<nav>
    <ul>


        <li><a href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php">PROFILE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">MANAGE SUB</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php">VIEW TITLES</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php">ADD TITLE</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php">MODIFY TITLE</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php">REMOVE TITLE</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="index.php">NEW RELEASES</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php">E-MAIL</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div id="contents">

    <h2>Hello ladies and gentlemen!</h2>
</div>

<div id="footer">
    Text here
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `position: absolute;` to `nav` and `margin:45px auto;` to `#contents`

Comment: Actually, when I did that it prevented my drop-down list from working. I didn't notice it at first.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that the `<nav>` is not clearing the floated list items.

Add `overflow:hidden;` to your `<nav>` element, and the problem should be resolved. `overflow:hidden;` will force a container to expand to the height of its floated children.

Comment: That creates space between the navigation element and the logo, so the background color appears. I still need the navigation bar to lie directly under the logo.

Comment: Put {overflow: hidden} on the nav li and nav li a elements, also. My guess is that line-height is a problem.